# howto get php PDO QUERY resultset in single array instead off nested in one

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I needed to change a query into a JOIN of two tables.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM table1 AS a JOIN table2 AS b USING(id) WHERE a.id= $id";
$stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

All off the sudden I cannot refer to each row value with `$rows['value']`
,BUT I need to use `$rows[0]['value']`.

How can I avoid this behavior and get the values in the row without using [0]?

Thanks, Richard

Comment: What's the query? Which method are you using to retrieve the result set? Could you just do `$rows = $rows[0];` ?

Comment: Thanks, I already used $rows[0] to get a quick fix. I edited the question.

Comment: I am eager to know, how do you think this array should look? Multiple rows in a "single array".

Comment: I can't see `Array[0][array(all the rows)]` here. From your own words above it's `Array[0]['scalar value']`. Can you clarify yourself at last? And I still do not understand how it is supposed to have **multiple** rows in a **single** associative array

Comment: I too don't understand what result you expect. If there is more than one row, how would you address them?

Comment: if you want just single row, do not use fetchAll, lol. There is another function to fetch a row. By the way, you are misusing PDO by passing variables directly into query. a placeholder should be used instead

Comment: Forget what I said, It is a single row. My explanation is maybe a bit off. All I was saying is that I need to use [0] to collect the column values for this JOIN query, but NOT for a select. I just try to make sense of that. Maybe it's just a PDO thing?

Comment: I am problably misusing PDO.I have an abstraction class, but it works only with select query's. For the more difficult ones, I just pass the whole query. Do you have an example with placeholders and what is the other to get a single row

Comment: @Richard if you expect only one row, use [`.fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: "collect the column values **for** this JOIN query"? what does it mean?

Comment: the values in the SELECT query that's using a JOIN to get the result from two tables. I am problably misusing PDO anyway, could you give me an example with placeholders.

Comment: placeholders has nothing to do with getting values off the database. it is about passing variables into query. there should be a question mark instead of $id in the query. You can find it on the man page for the execute method.

Comment: @Pekka, thanks. And @Col .Shrapnel I will look into the placeholder thing. I can ajust the function below to accept an array with the variables.How can I close this question as being answed if no one answered in an answerbox??

Answer (score 1):

If you expect only one row, use [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead of `fetchAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for returning one row:

```
$SQL = "SELECT myColumn FROM myTable";
$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
$STH->execute();
$row = $STH->fetch();
if ($STH->rowCount > 0) {
    $myColumn = $row['myColumn'];
}
```

And I use this for returning multiple rows:

```
$SQL = "SELECT myColumn FROM myTable";
$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($STH->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
        $myColumn = $row['myColumn'];
    }
}
```